# React Hooks - highlight day of the week based on the condition

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './Footer.css';
import axios from '../../axios';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import {
    Container, Row, Col, Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody,
    CardTitle
} from 'reactstrap';
const moment = require('moment');
const Footer = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState('');
    const [isBoolean, setBoolean] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const { data } = await axios.get('../days.json');
            setData(data);
            console.log(data);
        })();
        const today = moment().format('dddd');
        console.log(today);
    }, []);
    
    <ul className="footer-hours">
        {data && data.map((day, index) => {
            return (
                <li key={index}>{day.day}</li>
        );
        })}
       </ul>
```

i have a list of the weekdays, how can i based on current day dynamically add style to the current day from the rendered list? Currently i can only highlight or add style to all the items in a list. 
    Thank you.

Comment: Do you have "current day" stored anywhere? Or do you mean literally, today?

Comment: const today = moment().format('dddd'); - tells me the current day and this is the day i want to highlight from the rendered list.

Answer (score 0):

In your `map` call, you have both the day and the index of the day. Somewhere presumably you have something telling you what day you want to highlight. So you'd use that to put either `style` or (better) `className` on the day in question, e.g.:

```
return (
    <li> key={index} className={index === currentDayIndex ? "current" : null}>{day.day}</li>
);
```

...if you have the index of the day as `currentDayIndex`.

Comment: @Oleksii - That will return `"Tuesday"` or similar. Does that match up with `day.day`? If so, that's what your check would be.

Comment: Ahh was so simple!!! Thank you very much T.J. Crowder! Now i got it! ohh :)